# Add quotes to all elements inside of an array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1003667/4115275) for my own code which basically right now reads a value into a scalar which is pushed into an array called states. However, it doesnt properly hash the function like in the tutorial and I believe its because the contents of the array isn't properly quoted.

I've tried

```
foreach (@states)
{
      q($_);
}
```

and

```
push @states, q($key);
```

but neither produces the necessary output. Currently my output displays as

```
NY, NJ, MI , NJ
```

when using

```
print join(", ", @states);
```

I want it to display

```
 'NY', 'NJ', 'MI' , 'NJ'
```

Comment: also @keys here represents the scalar value im adding into states (such as NY, NJ etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add quotes around a value you can use double-quoted string interpolation:

```
"'$_'"
```

Or you can use string concatenation:

```
"'".$_."'"
```

So you can write your `foreach` loop as follows:

```
foreach (@states) {
    $_ = "'$_'";
}
```

Note that `$_` must be assigned, otherwise the body of the loop has no effect (this is the case with your `q($_);` code).

Full demo:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @states = qw(NY NJ MI NJ);

foreach (@states) {
    $_ = "'$_'";
}

print(join(', ', @states ));
```

---

```
'NY', 'NJ', 'MI', 'NJ'
```

Comment: I'm confused. Who downvoted my answer? And, more importantly, why?

Answer (score 13):

Take states, map them to quoted strings, join by comma:

```
my @states = qw( NY NJ MI );
print join ', ', map "'$_'", @states;
```

Comment: unfortunately im reading it in from a file and storing it into a scalar so i cant directly do the qw() method

Comment: but in your question you show you have a @states array; if you don't, please modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

One other way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @states = qw/ NY NJ MI NJ /;
my $output = join ', ', map qq/'$_'/, @states;

print $output;
```

Would result to a formatted list (string) of single quoted elements, each separated as you expect.

```
'NY', 'NJ', 'MI', 'NJ'
```